# Creating a new dataset for each combination of rows in groups

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I'm trying to create a dataset for each combination of rows from separate groups. Ideally, one row from each group would be selected and there would be a dataset for every combination. I have a dataset of that looks similar in structure to the sample below:

```
   Name  Group  Stat1  Stat2
1     1      a     63     38
2     2      a     33     62
3     3      b      3     66
4     4      b     57     67
5     5      c     42     69
6     6      c     47     14
7     7      c     16     10
8     8      d     21     46
9     9      d     72      1
```

Trying to get the end result of the first dataset to look like this:

```
    Name  Group  Stat1  Stat2
1      1      a     63     38
2      3      b      3     66
3      5      c     42     69
4      8      d     21     46
```

With the second data dataset looking like this:

```
    Name  Group  Stat1  Stat2
1      1      a     63     38
2      3      b      3     66
3      5      c     42     69
4      9      d     72      1
```

Until every combination has been exhausted. I've tried strategies using apply functions and `combn` but cannot seem to get the result I want. This does not seem too challenging to me conceptually, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to approach this. A simple solution is to just generate all 4 row combos, then subset to those with all distinct `Group` values. I named your data `df` and assumed `Name` would be unique row id. If that's not true, you could replace `df$Name` with `1:nrow(df)`

```
# All 4 row combos of row ids
combs <- combn(df$Name, 4)

# Match group labels to row ids
g <- matrix(df$Group[combs], nrow = 4)

# 4 row combs filtered to all distinct group vals 
combs <- combs[,apply(g, 2, function(i) all(!duplicated(i)))]

# For each 4 row combo, extract rows from the dataframe 
final_list <- apply(combs, 2, function(i) df[i,])

final_list[1:3]

[[1]]
  Name Group Stat1 Stat2
1    1     a    63    38
3    3     b     3    66
5    5     c    42    69
8    8     d    21    46

[[2]]
  Name Group Stat1 Stat2
1    1     a    63    38
3    3     b     3    66
5    5     c    42    69
9    9     d    72     1

[[3]]
  Name Group Stat1 Stat2
1    1     a    63    38
3    3     b     3    66
6    6     c    47    14
8    8     d    21    46
```

Comment: This is great! Really appreciate the response!

Comment: good post @dedemild, please accept the answer so if other people are looking for a similar solution they'll see it works